# programmatically edit tab order in pyqt4 python

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have a multiple textfield in my form. My problem is the tab order is wrong. Is there a way to edit tab order in code? Just like in QT Designer.

thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [QWidget.setTabOrder](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setTabOrder) to change the tab order of widgets:

```
self.setTabOrder(self.textboxA, self.textboxB)
self.setTabOrder(self.textboxB, self.textboxC)
self.setTabOrder(self.textboxC, self.textboxD)
```

Note how the tab order is linked from one widget to the next.

Comment: can you make it cycle, like `self.setTabOrder(self.textboxD, self.textboxA)`? Doesn't seem to work on me.

Comment: Hi Jason, were you able to find a way to make it cyclical? Currently looking to implement something very similar to this

Comment: For me, nothing extra is required - cycling is handled automatically. However, tab cycling only applies to the full set of widgets that can receive the tab focus. Subsets of widgets (such as a radio button groups) can be navigated using the up/down arrow keys, but they don't have a separate cycle of their own. (At least, that's the way it works for me on Linux). The tab order can be fully customised by reimplementing [focusNextPrevChild](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#focusNextPrevChild).