# Unable to setTabOrder in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

- Created an `ui` file using `Qt Designer`
- Then went to **Edit** and set the Tab order **Edit Tab Order** as guided by [Qt Designer's Tab Order Editing Mode](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/designer-tab-order.html)

Code

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PyQt5 import uic

qtCreatorFile = "registration.ui"
Ui_MainWindow, _ = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

class RegisterApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(RegisterApp,self).__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.enterButton.clicked.connect(self.registerFunc)

    def registerFunc(self) :

        '''
        Perform required operations
        '''
        self.close()
```

Tab functionally is not working as expected.

Tried to set programmatically edit tab order in pyqt5 python using [programmatically edit tab order in pyqt4 python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371007/programmatically-edit-tab-order-in-pyqt4-python)

Changed accordingly

```
class RegisterApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(RegisterApp,self).__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setTabOrder(self.ui.deviceName_box.focusProxy(), self.ui.registrationKey_box.focusProxy())
        self.setTabOrder(self.ui.registrationKey_box.focusProxy(), self.ui.enterButton.focusProxy())
        self.ui.enterButton.clicked.connect(self.registerFunc)
```

Still `Tab order not working`

What is going wrong?

Comment: With "Tab order not working" do you mean that it doesn't work at all or that it hasn't changed from what was before? Is there a specific reason for which you are you using focusProxy?

Comment: My bad. I used `QPlainTextEdit`, then changed to `QLineEdit` worked fine.